# Is there a way to apply future bar value?

Tags: pine-script

Pinescript begins calculations with the oldest bar and moves forward till current day bar. Is there a way to reference a current day bar or value calculated from the whole available range when calculating older bars?

Answer (score 1):

No. That would be cheating, wouldn't it? However, the opposite is possible.

If this is for display purposes, you can use the `offset` parameter of any `plot` function.

Comment: I would like to split the range between highest and lowest bar values in the whole range into X sections, then beginning with the first bar assign it's value to X(n) section. It's not possible right?